# Error during configurable product save in Magento 2 | Notice: Undefined variable: product in /module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Save.php

Tags: magento2.2, error, products

I am unable to save a configurable product. This is the error I am getting:

> Notice: Undefined variable: product in
>   /domains/devportal.flavourwarehouse.co.uk/http/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Save.php
>   on line 156

Saving simple products seems to work as expected.

Working on **Magento ver. 2.2.6** with products migrated from **Magento ver. 1.9**.

*If you need more information, please let me know.*

UPDATE:

In the exception logs, I got:

> [2019-01-29 11:28:18] main.CRITICAL: Warning: array_filter() expects
>   parameter 1 to be array, string given in
>   /domains/mydomain.com/http/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Initialization/Helper/Plugin/Configurable.php
>   on line 145 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Warning:
>   array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in
>   /domains/mydomain.com/http/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Initialization/Helper/Plugin/Configurable.php
>   on line 145 at
>   /domains/mydomain.com/http/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"}
>   []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a Magento core bug: if the `$product` initialization on line 101 throws an Exception:

```
$product = $this->initializationHelper->initialize(
    $this->productBuilder->build($this->getRequest())
);
```

the `$product` variable will be not set in the `catch` section. Try to debug which kind of exception was thrown and this will give you an answer how to avoid it.

**PS**: exception could be found in the Magento error log.

Comment: as per your answer, this is what is triggered after tying to save the product. Any ideas how to solve the problem?

Comment: @BareFeet What inside the `$associatedProductIds` on line 131 in `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Initialization/Helper/Plugin/Configurable.php`?

Comment: The variable was empty, I managed to find the core problem; my custom theme had a "required" attribute that was breaking the site. Thank you kindly for your support. You directed my in the correct way.

Comment: @BareFeet I was glad to help you :)